# Do mobile devices have enough CPU to support HTTPS for all of a website's traffic?

Tags: android, performance, ios, mobile, https

We are developing a web application intended for use on smartphones and other mobile devices, and we are thinking about running all traffic through HTTPS to make security simpler.

I know that the CPU cost of HTTPS encryption for bigger computers is fairly trivial, but is this also true for modern smartphones like iPhone and Android?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but is an interesting and relevant read about Google's attempt to create a faster HTTP protocol that requires additional processing on the client-side (such as gzip and HTTPS): http://arstechnica.com/web/news/2009/11/spdy-google-wants-to-speed-up-the-web-by-ditching-http.ars

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Considering that the cpu of such a device runs at 400 MHz or higher, and that https has been around for decades running on slower cpu's, I'd say there is no problem with that.

Comment: Just want to add: But you may still have slowdowns thanks to the SSL handshake, especially over higher-latency mobile connections: http://www.semicomplete.com/blog/geekery/ssl-latency.html

Comment: @Yoni true. Yet another reason to let all http traffic originate from one server (actually: hostname with fixed ip) greatly reducing the number of connections that need to be set up. One SO pageview leads to 9 (nine!) different hosts. Streamlining things like that easily offsets any slowdown by https.

Comment: Won't matter unless keepalive's on, though; I haven't seen many Android apps trying to use that (particularly, I can't imagine that'd be especially pleasant on battery life, anyways), but see http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/ConnectionReuseStrategy.html.

Comment: For one pageview with 10 images, 5 css files and 2 js includes, I'm 99% confident that every modern browser (phone or otherwise) uses keepalive and gets them over one TCP connection. A second pageview may need a new connection, yes.

Comment: for a mobile browser, definitely; I guess I'm also thinking app development. For the OP's question though, I'd definitely imagine so.

Comment: @OP: If it makes your app simpler and more reliable, then just do it.  A working, secure app is better than a fast, crashy one.  Next year the phones will be faster and have better batteries anyway.  Premature optimization is the root of all evil.